# columns using string formatting python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bash

I'm trying to replicate the ls function in bash with columns like this:
[image]

I tried .format to add padding to the file names but im still not getting the desired output
the last column overflows everytime.

```
def show_dirs():
    filelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    filelist.sort()

    scr_width = int(os.popen("stty size", "r").read().split()[1])
    max_len = -1
    for file_len in filelist:
        if len(file_len) > max_len and scr_width > max_len*2:
            max_len = len(file_len)
            mlen = max_len #+ 1

    print(color["cyan"] + "Files in the current directory")

    if scr_width < mlen:
        mlen = scr_width

    line = ""
    for count, _file in enumerate(filelist):
        if os.path.isdir(_file):
            _file = _file + os.sep
            st = "[{0:>2}] {1:<{mlen}}".format(str(count + 1), _file, mlen=mlen)
            if len(line) % scr_width > len(st):
                line = line + color["green"] + st
            else:
                line = line + "\n" + color["green"] + st
        else:
            st = "[{0:>2}] {1:<{mlen}}".format(str(count + 1), _file, mlen=mlen)
            if len(line) % scr_width > len(st):
                line = line + color["cyan"] + st
            else:
                line = line + "\n" + color["cyan"] + st
    print(line)
```

I get this output:

[image]

Comment: I find this question to be interesting. Other than brute force, I cannot think of a good method for determining how many columns of text can ft across a screen of a given width. Even determining an upper bound on this number is tough, because a list of inputs may exist that would not fit in `N` columns, but would in `N+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved my algorithm and now it works fine when the terminal size is fixed

```
color = {
    "red": "\033[31m",
    "green": "\033[32m",
    "orange": "\033[33m",
    "purple": "\033[35m",
    "cyan": "\033[36m",
    "yellow": "\033[93m",
}


def show_dirs(path=os.getcwd()):
    print(color["cyan"] + "Files in the current directory")
    filelist = os.listdir(path)
    filelist.sort()

    #index padding
    ind = len(filelist)
    if ind >= 1000:
        ind = 4
    elif ind >= 100:
        ind = 3
    elif ind >= 10:
        ind = 2
    else:
        ind = 1

    scr_width = int(os.get_terminal_size()[0]) #terminal width
    mlen = max(len(word) for word in filelist) + 1 #column width
    cols = scr_width // mlen #possible columns

    if scr_width < mlen:
        mlen = scr_width

    line = ""
    lst = []
    for count, _file in enumerate(filelist, start=1):
        if os.path.isdir(_file):
            _file = _file + os.sep
            st = "[{0:>{ind}}] {1:<{mlen}}".format(
                str(count), _file, mlen=mlen, ind=ind
            )
            if scr_width - ((len(line) - cols * 5) % scr_width) > len(st): # - cols * 5 to compensate the length of color codes
                line = line + color["cyan"] + st
            else:
                lst.append(line)
                line = color["cyan"] + st

        else:
            st = "[{0:>{ind}}] {1:<{mlen}}".format(
                str(count), _file, mlen=mlen, ind=ind
            )
            if scr_width - ((len(line) - cols * 5) % scr_width) > len(st): # - cols * 5 to compensate the length of color codes
                line = line + color["green"] + st
            else:
                lst.append(line)
                line = color["green"] + st
    if lst == []:
        lst.append(line)
    print("\n".join(lst))
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that column output of a list of arbitrary strings is done by [the Linux column command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html). One option is to assume the existence of this command on your system (it exists in my environment) and to use it as an out-of-process output filter.

Another option is to dig deeper into the source code of `columns`, and reimplement it in Python, possibly as a generator function. I found a pointer [in GitHub](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c). Note that this is over 800 lines of C code.

You can also create Python binding for the core functionality of that C code, which would yield a better performing code. Sadly I do not have experience with integrating C code into Python.

If you decide to opt for the second alternative, you can post your implementation as an answer here.

Comment: i looked into the source code of column command but it was too complex

Comment: I came up with a solution but it only works if the terminal size dosen't change 
so I am thinking of making a function to refresh the screen with the new columns if the terminal size is changed

Comment: @AakashSingh - do not that your algorithm uses a fixed column width (I state this based on you output), while the Linux columns (or ls) algorithm only uses columns as wide as the widest element *in the column*. So, what you are implementing is not what you stated you wanted.